# Java RequestDispatcher returns null in Jetty Embedded app

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have the following code

```
//response.sendRedirect("Cmmdc");
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("Cmmdc");
System.out.println(requestDispatcher);--- **NULL**
requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

My main:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
server.setHandler(handler);

handler.addServletWithMapping(Start.class, "/Start");
handler.addServletWithMapping(Cmmdc.class, "/Cmmdc");
handler.addServletWithMapping(OptiuneServlet.class, "/OptiuneServlet");
handler.addServletWithMapping(Prim.class, "/Prim");
handler.addServletWithMapping(ValidatorCMMDC.class, "/ValidatorCMMDC");
handler.addServletWithMapping(ValidatorPrim.class, "/ValidatorPrim");
System.out.println("Start server jetty embedded");
server.start();
server.join();
```

My question is how should I call the cmmdc servlet to return a reference and not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestDispatcher` **requires** a `ServletContext` (no way around that).

Your setup has none.

Don't use `ServletHandler` directly like that, use `ServletContextHandler` instead.

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(context);
context.addServlet(Start.class, "/Start");
// etc ...
server.start();
server.join();
```